# Clang Core Dumps On Windows

Tags: clang, llvm

I installed Clang stable build 7.01 for windows 64 bit pre-built binaries on my Windows 7 machine and i cannot get it to run. By that i mean it immediately core dumps before even parsing the command line options. The dump file doesnt help me much. Here is the output:

```
LLVM ERROR: out of memory
Wrote crash dump file "C:\Users\Lewis\AppData\Local\Temp\clang.exe-84805c.dmp"
0x0000000140A7F506 (0x0000000000000016 0x00000001425A4EFF 0x0000000140A7F500 0x0000000000000000)
0x00000001425A5275 (0x0000000000B9DD01 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000DBEB90)
0x000000014259CA84 (0x0000000000000002 0x0000000000DBEB90 0x0000000000B9DA60 0x00000001425E0B3E)
0x0000000140A7D55B (0x0000000000DB8880 0x0000000000B9DCC8 0x0000000000B9DCD8 0x0000000000000000)
0x0000000140A5F3EE (0x0000000000D84A20 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000D20000)
0x0000000140FC922D (0x0000000000B9E5A0 0x0000000000B9DF70 0x0000000000000000 0x00000001425E0104)
0x0000000140F27434 (0x0000000000D20230 0x0000000000D20230 0x0000000000D204A8 0x0000000000D25478)
0x0000000140F2B858 (0x0000000000D20158 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000003)
0x000000013F6E3F9D (0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x01D4A35EF2AE27A0)
0x000000014258A7E8 (0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000)
0x00000000776B59CD (0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000), BaseThreadInitThunk() + 0xD bytes(s)
0x000000007781385D (0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000), RtlUserThreadStart() + 0x1D bytes(s)
```

Does anyone have any Idea what could be causing this?
Some things I have tried:

1. seen somewhere that installing Mingw might help. Didnt make a difference.
2. Removed everything from path other than the c:\clang directory
3. Moved a test file to the clang directory and still same result.
4. figured out that running clang with no arguments. same result.
5. Ran as Administrator

I suspect that there is a missing runtime dll or file, but shouldnt a clean install have installed all the needed files?
Also i have 4 GB memory (1.5 used by system) with a quad core cpu so i doubt its running out of actual memory on startup.

EDIT: Im starting to narrow in on this problem. Ive literally spent a week now trying to get clang to start on my windows 7 machine. Ive downloaded and installed every vc redist, installed numerous updates and KB fixes. Still nothing. Using dependancy walker ive discovered that clang fails to load DLL files from the WINRT api set.Specifically the whole "API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-STRING-L1-1-0.DLL" not found- family of problems. Ive coppied all 41 dlls from the win 10 redist folder in the win 10 sdk over to the clang folder and still no joy. will i not be able to run clang on windows 7?

EDIT 2: For anyone coming here with the same problem ive discovered the problem and it is deep. Apparently Clang/LLVM for Windows is compiled by (or compiled against libraries in) Visual Studio. Really Clang...? Why cant you compile your compiler with your own compiler? Eat your own dog food as they say. That being said, i discovered this by installing a debug build of llvm which gave me some better error diagnoatics. Following the error codes down the deep google rabbit hole brought me to the mailing list for llvm from 2 years ago where they discussed this problem and also discussed moving compilation from VS 2013 to VS 2015. The problem is that compiling with VS (Visual Studio) creates a dependancy on the 64 bit DIA (Debug Interface Access) dll which is only installed on systems with visual studio installed (and on  Windows 10 apparently). Thats why it wasnt working on my system, I had installed clang for the very reason that I didnt want to install the monster 10 gigabyte Visual STudio on my computer. However, after discovering this I relinquished my stubborness and installed it. Boom! Clang works like a charm.